# Duplicate items not supported keeps reappearing

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I keep getting this error below, and each time I need to delete the file specified to fix it. This happens when I use the designer.

> The item "obj\Debug\Supermarket.frmCustomer.resources" was specified
>   more than once in the "Resources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not
>   supported by the "Resources" parameter.   Supermarket

Is there any permanent solution to this, as it happens to any of the form I edit using the Visual Studio designer?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/df3bee5f-8081-4425-aca7-70bfbc15fb30

Comment: hello, my problems is that i have tried all those, but it keeps reappearing everytime i fix it. what could be causing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem! I simply created another project and imported all my classes and resources.

Answer (score 0):

You copy file in solution, open it in form designer and rename it. VC rename ALL classes, include OLD file.

1. Exclude from Project item "Supermarket.frmCustomer.cs"
2. open old file in designer and rename class to old name
3. Include to Project item "Supermarket.frmCustomer.cs"